# ExtJS 7 - How to customize the modern.jsonp manifest file?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to get my head around ExtJs 7 code. Seeing various default examples
There is a file defining the manifest modern.jsonp / classic.json

As a rule, a huge number of libraries are included in these files. Tell me how to customize the manifest yourself and only connect what I need?

```
Ext.Microloader.setManifest(
{"paths":
{
"Ext":"ext/modern/modern/src"
}
,"loadOrder":
[
{"path":"ext/packages/core/src/Ext.js","requires":[1],"uses":[],"idx":0},
{"path":"ext/modern/modern/overrides/init.js","requires":[],"uses":[],"idx":1},
{"path":"ext/packages/core/src/lang/Error.js",
"requires":[0],"uses":[],"idx":2},{"path":"ext/packages/core/src/lang/Array.js",
"requires":[0,2],"uses":[4],"idx":3},{"path":"ext/packages/core/src/lang/Assert.js",
"requires":[0,2],"uses":[],"idx":4},{"path":"ext/packages/core/src/lang/String.js",
"requires":[0,3],"uses":[],"idx":5},{"path":"ext/packages/core/src/lang/Date.js",
"requires":[0,5],"uses":[3],"idx":6}
```

And there are hundreds of such lines .. many files are clearly not required by my project, but if I remove some line, then for some reason an error occurs.
All these lines are linked to each other.
How do I generate a new jsonp?

My project is meant to be a website I basically don't need compilation

Comment: I'm sorry for the question, but what for? May be you need another solution...

Comment: The manifest is auto maintained.  When you build in production mode it will only include the files that are "required" and cmd will bundle in one file and compress.  "testing" mode is the same but leaves out the compress step so you can debug if something works in development but not in production.

Comment: I don't need to compile via CMD, I have a GPL project that will open in the browser as a web site.
How do I know what the autoloader needs and how do I create my own jsonp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want these files to be added to your `.gitignore`, because they are auto-generated by Sencha CMD.

The files inside the `*.json` and `*.jsonp` are added by your requirements.

**example**

```
Ext.define('MyNamespace.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    requires: [
        'MyNamespace.view.List',
        'PackageA.TestView'
    ],
    uses: [
        'MyNamespace.helper.Dom'
    ]
});
```

Sencha CMD runs through the main and finds requires. In order it will add all requirements after the main view.

As soon as it finds `uses` it will add these at the end, because it seems they are not important for the order.

**answer**
You can controll the order of the files by changing the requirements or use `uses`.

Comment: Many thanks, I am beginning to understand.

Now I have the following task: I have a regular gpu project based on the Sencha example. How do I regenerate the modern.jsonp file? Now it is from an old project and contains a lot of unnecessary things.

Comment: How can I figure out what exactly my ExtJS project needs? What paths should I write in * .jsonp?

Comment: Delete all jsonp files and run `sencha app watch` inside the app-folder, this will create the jsonp file

Comment: @webpuper you can regenerate all application metadata including classic/modern.json* by running *sencha app refresh*